# Unable to recover hard disk drive after failed formatting due to sudden power outage

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, mbr

I was formatting a [WD Caviar Blue 640GB](https://support-en.wd.com/app/products/product-detail/p/146) hard drive using Darik's Boot and Nuke (writing zeros method), and suddenly power in the house went out so computer did shot down. It was on about 30% on pass 1 of 3 passes.

When I booted computer to start the process again, hard drive is not listed anymore. I tried rebuilding and deleting MBR using installation disk, Hirens, even Windows Data Lifeguard Diagnostics say's the MBR table is locked by another program and bunch of other software, but still can't make it work. In Windows disk manager shows disk unknown not initialized I/O error. Tried fixing with DiskPart but no success.

Is there any other way to fix it?

### I used the folowing software to test HDD:

- HDDScan v4.0
- HDTune v2.55
- WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostics v1.31
- AOMEI Partition Assistant v7.0.1
- EaseUS Partition Master 13.0
- EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard
- Darik’s Boot and Nuke (DBAN)
- Hard Disk Sentinel
- MBRWizard 3.0.73
- DISKPART (Windows)
- bootrec.exe (Console using Windows installation disc)

### OS used for testing:

- Linux Mint
- Arch Linux
- Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried using TestDisk? [TestDisk Step By Step](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

Comment: Have you tried a live Linux image? If it doesn't show up for the Linux kernel, and low level tools, then you are probably screwed.  If Linux sees it then I can tell you how to recover the disk.

Comment: Adding onto @GuyGastineau’s comment, if you can boot into Linux you can `dd if=/dev/null of=<your disk>` to nuke the MBR/GPT partitions regardless of file locks.

Comment: Can you in Disk Management : Right-click the disk and select Initialize Disk, choose partition style as MBR/GPT and OK? [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/initialize-new-disks)

Comment: @harrymc I can't initialize disk. Fow MBR show error. For GPT shows not enough space unable to init (Because it shows 0 GB).

Comment: @GuyGastineau What type of linux do you reccomend for testing?

Comment: I always suggest an Arch Linux thumb drive for this kind of work, but if you are new to *nix it is not very friendly. You might like the live environment shipped by Kali Linux or Ubuntu.  Basically, if the drive shows up as /dev/sdx (x is a placeholder here) then you can write a new mbr/gpt with fdisk.  You can also write zeros to the drive with the command dd.  It is fast and runs in the terminal.  Be careful not to overwrite the wrong drive though. Let me know if you trouble shoot it with Linux and have any more questions.

Comment: @GuyGastineau Tried with Arch and Mint Linux but drive doesn't show up, so i'm unable to pick partition. Only my usb stick is displayed in partition list.

Comment: @Slasher _"drive doesn't show up,"_ What does it means? Have you seen if there is the `/dev/sd...` or `/dev/hd...` that is not the working HDD? It should be useful to know where (on which sector) it stopped when there was the power failure, if you have some log. Please [edit] your question adding links to the program you were using.

Comment: Did you try lsblk from the terminal?

Comment: 11 years for a hard drive is an admirable lifespan for a hard drive that was most likely released 10 years ago and has a 3 year warranty at best. Don’t look at the drive as having died, rather recognize it’s admirable life. And if you like that specific drive you can get a similar model for $40 or so on eBay anyway. Any time and effort spent on this drive is fairly wasted. Worried about data on the drive? Just dismantle it and smash the platters with a hammer. Keep the magnets. The drive’s dead, Jim.

Comment: Could you give shred on linux a shot - wipe the device not the partition? That said, for the size/capasity/age, it feels like its a bit of a waste of time

Comment: @Candunc+ copying from `/dev/zero` _might_ help depending on what the actual disk hardware state is, but `/dev/null` absolutely won't.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yep, /dev/zero is what I meant. Thanks for catching that. I’ve had Mac OS refuse to format because of corrupted partitions and zeroing it can be used as a last resort.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried TestDisk Step By Step, but my hard drive is not even detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practically, the disk is dead, but I've found a few things that could wring a *little* life off of a dead drive.

If your *filesystem* alone is the issue, you could run a tool that works device level, like shred in order to zero out the drive completely, and doing a reformat. I'd recommend a "full" format, and doublechecking by using a badblocks option (in linux) or chkdsk in windows with the [appropriate switches](https://superuser.com/a/338093/10165) - /b would work for ntfs, and /R for other filesystems.

In theory zeroing out and reformatting the drive kicks in the drive's own bad block checking and error correction, and I've kind of gotten a 'dead' drive that underwent a similar scenario running for a short time (then dying, then coming back to life, then dying again finally).

That said, you really also need to consider the health of the drive as a whole. Modern drives have a reasonable ability to self test. I'm a fan of [gsmartcontrol](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads) since it highlights problem values, but I'd recommend running a short test, then if it passes a long test. If either disk health checks fail, you're better off binning the drive.

Smart Statistics are also handy - I've [another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/61899/will-reformatting-my-hard-drive-fix-bad-sectors-on-it/620903#620903) that goes into detail on these, and if you can't get smart statistics, well the drive is *also* dead

Answer (score 4):

Age can be a factor. If it's true that the hard drive is 11 years old, it's about time to replace it.

In my experience, any hardware that's is more than 5 years old can be unreliable. That's just me speaking from my experience.

With what you have already done, it would be best use of your time to replace the hardware. Any extra effort is just a waste.

Hard drives are inexpensive these days. Get one from a reputable company, Best Buys, New Egg, etc.

Comment: This is genuinely the only reasonable and realistic answer here.

Comment: Re: the last line: Is avoid a used hard drive at all costs. You don’t know what kind of abuse they’ve been through.

Answer (score 2):

Formatting only affects the data itself while disk recognition is handled by a chip inside the HDD. That's mean your formatting cannot be the cause as long as data and disk recognition are handled by different parts.

So the most probable scenario is the chip didn't supported the power loss, maybe he suffered from a temporary high tension (preceding the power loss in your house) that killed your HDD.